# Cant correctly turn this set of functions into a working class (p5.js)

Tags: javascript, class, oop, object, p5.js

I am turning a set of functions which create a tree into a class, however where the functions create a large branched out tree, the class version is not correctly sketching the tree as it does in the function. I am not highly experienced with javascript and oop, so spotting the problem here is very frustrating and difficult for me, I would appreciate if someone could point out what I need to change about the class so It would display correctly.

I have compared the code side by side trying to find if there is any differences, but I feel the problem is due to the differences in functions and methods within a class, which makes it very hard for me to identify to spot.

The code I am trying to fix can be found here: https://editor.p5js.org/remcqueen/sketches/S1ETz7WfV

The expected result of the code is the same as the function version, which can be found here: https://editor.p5js.org/remcqueen/sketches/B1HdvWbzN

A full leafless tree should be generated. however what is currently shown is quite different.

I would be grateful to anybody who takes a look at this problem to help solve it.

Here is the class that I'm trying to fix:

```
class createTree {

  constructor() {
    this.tree = createGraphics(width-10, height-10);
    this.n = 0;
  }

  draw() {
    this.tree.beginShape();
    this.tree.noStroke();
    this.tree.background(0,0);
    for (this.i = 0; this.i < 3; this.i++) {
        this.tree.fill(map(this.i, 0, 2, 60, 20));
        this.branch(width/2, height, 70, -HALF_PI, 150, 0);
    }
    this.tree.endShape();
    image(this.tree, 5, 5);
  }


  branch(x, y, bSize, theta, bLength, pos) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.bSize = bSize;
    this.theta = theta;
    this.bLength = bLength;
    this.pos = pos;
    this.n += 0.01;
    this.diam = lerp(this.bSize, 0.7 * this.bSize, this.pos / this.bLength);
    this.diam *= map(noise(this.n), 0, 1, 0.4, 1.6);

    this.tree.ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.diam, this.diam);
    if (this.bSize > 0.6) {
        if (this.pos < this.bLength) {
            this.x += cos(this.theta + random(-PI / 10, PI / 10));
            this.y += sin(this.theta + random(-PI / 10, PI / 10));
            this.branch(this.x, this.y, this.bSize, this.theta, this.bLength, this.pos + 1);
        } else {
            this.drawLeftBranch = random(1) > 0.1;
            this.drawRightBranch = random(1) > 0.1;
            if (this.drawLeftBranch) this.branch(this.x, this.y, random(0.5, 0.7) * this.bSize, this.theta - random(PI / 15, PI / 5), random(0.6, 0.8) * this.bLength, 0);
            if (this.drawRightBranch) this.branch(this.x, this.y, random(0.5, 0.7) * this.bSize, this.theta + random(PI / 15, PI / 5), random(0.6, 0.8) * this.bLength, 0);

            if (!this.drawLeftBranch && !this.drawRightBranch) {
                this.tree.push()
                this.tree.translate(this.x, this.y);
                this.tree.rotate(this.theta);
                this.tree.quad(0, -this.diam / 2, 2 * this.diam, -this.diam / 6, 2 * this.diam, this.diam / 6, 0, this.diam / 2);
                this.tree.pop();
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is that `draw()` should be a public function as `setup()` and not class functions. When I went to [**getting started page**](https://p5js.org/get-started/) I saw this structure. And as I read your code you call `draw()` only once and there is a loop of 3 so only 3 branches are drawn, try calling `draw()` more times. Yes update your `draw()` method and your tree might become tree :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response but this the issue and isn't what's causing the problem.

Comment: Okay mate I will tell you what is the problem with your code. All variables in `brach()` method should be local not class properties. Go and remove all `this.` only leave  `this.n`. All `x, y, bSize, theta, bLength, pos, drawLeftBranch, drawRightBranch` should be local variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting instance variables all over the place where what you really want are variables local to the function. When you set the variables on the instance they are shared during the recursion and this isn't what you want. For example you need all the parameters of the function to be local to the function:

Adding them to `this` is breaking everything:

```
branch(x, y, bSize, theta, bLength, pos) {
   this.x = x;  // <-- don't do that
   this.y = y;
 // etc
}
```

Here's a cleaned up snippet:

```js
var a;
function setup() {
  createCanvas(900, 700);
  colorMode(HSB);
  noLoop();
  noStroke();
  a = new createTree();
  a.draw();
}

class createTree {

  constructor() {
    this.tree = createGraphics(width, height);
    this.n = 0;
  }

  draw() {
    this.tree.beginShape();
    this.tree.noStroke();
    this.tree.background(0,0);
  
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        this.tree.fill(map(i, 0, 2, 60, 20));
        this.branch(width/2, height, 70, -HALF_PI, 150, 0);
    }
    this.tree.endShape();
    image(this.tree, 5, 5);
  }


  branch(x, y, bSize, theta, bLength, pos) {
    
    this.n += 0.01;
    let diam = lerp(bSize, 0.7 * bSize, pos / bLength);
    diam *= map(noise(this.n), 0, 1, 0.4, 1.6);

    this.tree.ellipse(x, y, diam, diam);
    if (bSize > 0.6) {
        if (pos < bLength) {
            x += cos(theta + random(-PI / 10, PI / 10));
            y += sin(theta + random(-PI / 10, PI / 10));
            this.branch( x, y, bSize, theta, bLength, pos + 1);
        } else {
            let drawLeftBranch = random(1) > 0.1;
            let drawRightBranch = random(1) > 0.1;
            if (drawLeftBranch) this.branch(x, y, random(0.5, 0.7) * bSize, theta - random(PI / 15, PI / 5), random(0.6, 0.8) * bLength, 0);
            if (drawRightBranch) this.branch(x, y, random(0.5, 0.7) * bSize, theta + random(PI / 15, PI / 5), random(0.6, 0.8) * bLength, 0);

            if (!drawLeftBranch && !drawRightBranch) {
                this.tree.push()
                this.tree.translate(x, y);
                this.tree.rotate(theta);
                this.tree.quad(0, -diam / 2, 2 * diam, -diam / 6, 2 * diam, diam / 6, 0, diam / 2);
                this.tree.pop();
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.2/p5.min.js"></script>
```